# Rename [girl] tag to clarify that it is not about a general topic about girl

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retagging

There is a [girl](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/girl) tag which is actually about *GIRL*, an animation short by Hibiki Yoshizaki published on [Japan Animator Expo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan_Animator_Expo). However, recent questions tagged with this were usually about ID requests for anime/manga with girl characters.

This issue was brought up once in [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54635020#54635020),

> i wonder if we should change the tag itself? or maybe add a note to it's usage as i see it alot on id requests

which I somewhat agree with.

While the tag already has an excerpt (which unfortunately is not effective), without any additional context, the current name itself also looks like a meta tag, possibly affecting its misusage.

I also proposed some alternatives in [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54635567#54635567), like [girl-hibiki-yoshizaki](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/girl-hibiki-yoshizaki) or [girl-japan-animator-expo](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/girl-japan-animator-expo).

But still, should the tag be renamed at all? If so, to what name?

---

<sup>P.S.: While this discussion is partially initiated due to the common mistagging with ID requests, I acknowledge that renaming this tag might *not* reduce future ID requests.</sup>

Comment: [Another one](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/58008/35679)....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Tag merged to [girl-daoko](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/girl-daoko)*

---

We have no baseline policy for such cases. But we typically don't attach the director to works in particular or events. We could start outlining short length (especially ones with very generic names), one-off works with the `-short` syntax.

Alternatively, in the case of this particular work, it features the rapper DAOKO. We can render the tag as `girl-daoko`, in the context as "Girl" feat. DAOKO, even if it is a collaboration work, DAOKO's music is the primary fixture and he has first credit. If we use this as a precedent, we could attach the name of the first credit (we can go off a combination of press releases and/or the average of general internet consensus for this) to future works that have short and or generic titles to different site them.

I do not believe that adding the event to the tag would be a good syntax for classification as I feel that it belongs as its own standalone tag along with that of the director. In the case of this particular work, the performing art's name stands out above the expo and the director amongst the mainstream masses.

Comment: Fair point about not attaching the director's name, I was thinking more of using the author's name (in general case) instead. Also, after some consideration, while `girl-short` is suitable, my personal feeling is that it's still more prone to misusage (e.g. "a short girl") than `girl-daoko`, which hopefully can make the poster to think twice... but feel free to peruse either.